# Extract info with curl or something

Tags: curl

I plan to write a script for automatic VirtualBox build
I see every release VirtualBox put a version (of course) and 
a release version.

In this example

```
http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.6/VirtualBox-5.0.6-103037-Linux_amd64.run
```

5.0.6 is version and 103037 is release version, probably a git revision.

Every new version, of course there is a new release version, is it possible
to extract without knowing the release version, maybe with curl or something?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, exactly. Are you trying to get the new download URL (and download Virtualbox) every time a new release comes up?

Comment: Yes,i want to get new downlaod url when release come up.

Comment: Please see my answer below. It outputs the complete URL to stdout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty clean, but relies on `lynx` to dump links (rather than parsing the source HTML with regex or something):

`wget -q "https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads" -O - | lynx -stdin -dump -listonly | grep -Eo 'http.+amd64.run$'`

The last `grep` regex assumes you need the amd64 version.

Same thing with `curl`:

`curl -s "https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads" | lynx -stdin -dump -listonly | grep -Eo 'http.+amd64.run$'`

UPDATE: It has been correctly pointed out that calling `wget` or `curl` is not needed:

`lynx -dump -listonly "https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads" | grep -Eo 'http.+amd64.run$'`

Comment: why not just `lynx -dump -listonly "https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads" | grep -Eo 'http.+amd64.run$'`

Comment: yep, that's shorter. I guess I just like the `-stdin` option of `lynx` ;) Thanks, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

using wget only, no need for release version, only version is required:

```
wget -e robots=off -nd -r --no-parent -A 'VirtualBox-5.0.6-*-Linux_amd64.run' http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.6/
```

wget supports globing in recursive mode as part of it's accept pattern, so:

`-r` : recursive download
`--no-parent` : don't recurse into `..`
`-A 'VirtualBox-5.0.6-*-Linux_amd64.run'` : use acceptance pattern with glob
 `-e robots=off` : don't download robots.txt
`-nd` : don't create any subdirectories locally

Using an environment variable for version is of course possible:

```
VER=5.0.6
wget -e robots=off -nd -r --no-parent -A "VirtualBox-${VER}-*-Linux_amd64.run" http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/${VER}/
```

VER can actually be retrieved from http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/LATEST.TXT so this becomes:

```
VER=$(wget -O - http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/LATEST.TXT)
wget -e robots=off -nd -r --no-parent -A "VirtualBox-${VER}-*-Linux_amd64.run" http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/${VER}/
```

Or use curl or lynx to extract the version info...

If used in a cron script, you can equate ver each day to local ver env var (wget to NEWVER) and only download when NEWVER diff from current VER